# AzureDevOps dotnetcorecli does not build solution's class libraries and incorrectly looks for them in Artifacts

Tags: azure-pipelines, dotnetcorecli

I have a simple .NET solution like below:

```
My Solution
   ClassLibA
   ClassLibB
   MyAspNetCoreApp
```

In AzureDevOps pipeline I have also created a simple and straightforward pipeline:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: 'Default'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
  inputs:
    version: 6.x

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: './nuget.config'
  
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'MyAspNetCoreApp'
```

The `nuget.config` pointed in the `NuGetCommand@2` task is as follows:

```xml
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="mynuget" value="https://www.azuredevops.web/MyCollection/_packaging/mynuget/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

In fact, I created a nuget feed in AzureDevOps artifacts for my general-purpose libraries and published them into that feed (those libraries are independent of the above solution).

Example:

```
My Solution
   ClassLibA
      dependencies
         Packages
           GeneralLibX (2.0.0)
           GeneralLibY (1.1.0)
   ClassLibB
   MyAspNetCoreApp
```

The first 3 steps of the pipeline (cloning the solution's repo, installing .NET SDK, installing nuget packages) work fine. However, when the process reaches to the final meat (building the project), it goes bloody with a "Unable to load the service index for source" error.

```
##[section]Starting: DotNetCoreCLI
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.153.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
[command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
[command]C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\winx64\_work\_tool\dotnet\dotnet.exe build C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\winx64\_work\1\s\MyAspNetCoreApp
MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\winx64\_work\1\s\ClassLibA\ClassLibA.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://www.azuredevops.web/MyCollection/_packaging/mynuget/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\winx64\_work\1\s\MyAspNetCoreApp\MyAspNetCoreApp.csproj]
C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\winx64\_work\1\s\ClassLibB\ClassLibB.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://www.azuredevops.web/MyCollection/_packaging/mynuget/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\winx64\_work\1\s\MyAspNetCoreApp\MyAspNetCoreApp.csproj]
...
```

The build process then traps in an unlimited loop and I have no choice but to cancel it.

Could anybody explains why dotnetcli does not build the class libraries in the solution and instead, incorrectly tries to look for their built version in the artifacts' nuget feed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're **telling** it to look in the artifacts feed with your NuGet.config.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build all the **`.csproj`** under the solution, you can set the value of **`projects`** field to be '**`**/*.csproj`**' on the **`DotNetCoreCLI@2`** task.

In addition, when you run a dotnet command, by default, it will run all the previous processes in the lift-cycle. For example:

- If you run '**`dotnet build`**', it will first run '**`dotnet restore`**' process and then '**`dotnet build`**' process by default.
- If you run '**`dotnet publish`**', it will run the previous '**`dotnet restore`**' and '**`dotnet build`**' processes by default, then run '**`dotnet publish`**'.

Since you have executed **`NuGet restore`** using the **`NuGetCommand@2`** task to restore packages before the dotnet build task, you can add the argument '**`--no-restore`**' to the dotnet build task to skip the restore process before the build process.

So, you can reference below sample to update your YAML:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '-c $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore'
```

---

**EDIT:**

If your apps are **.NET Core** or **.NET Standard**, it is recommended to use the **`DotNetCoreCLI@2`** task to run the '**`dotnet restore`**' command to restore the packages.

```yaml
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: './nuget.config'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '-c $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore'
```

---

**EDIT_2:**

You can try the following ways:

1. If the feed is in current Azure DevOps organization which the pipeline is in, you can configure the '**`dotnet restore`**' task like as below to authenticate the feed.

   ```yaml
   - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
     displayName: 'dotnet restore'
     inputs:
       command: restore
       projects: '**/*.csproj'
       vstsFeed: '{feed_name}'  # Search and restore packages from the specified feed within current organization.
       includeNuGetOrg: true  # Also search and restore public packages from NuGet.org.
   ```

   Or like this when using **`nuget.config`**.

   ```yaml
   - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
     displayName: 'dotnet restore'
     inputs:
       command: restore
       projects: '**/*.csproj'
       feedsToUse: config
       nugetConfigPath: './nuget.config'
   ```
2. If the feed is outside current organization, you can do like as below.

   - Go to **Project Settings** > **Service connections** to create a [NuGet service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#nuget-service-connection) to the outside feed.
   - Then you can configure the '**`dotnet restore`**' task like as below.

     ```yaml
     - task: NuGetCommand@2
       displayName: 'NuGet restore'
       inputs:
         feedsToUse: config
         nugetConfigPath: './nuget.config'
         externalFeedCredentials: '{name of NuGet service connection}'
     ```

---

Comment: Thank you Bright Ran. I added the arguments as you said, The error changed to this:

Assets file 'C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\winx64\_work\1\s\MyAspNetCoreApp\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

Comment: @MansoorOmrani, I updated my above answer with more information (see **EDIT**). Check and try it.

Comment: Thank you again @Bright Ran. There is still an error. It seems dotnet restore does not use nuget.config at the solution root directory despite using 'nugetConfigPath' option.

Comment: @MansoorOmrani, Do you put the **`nuget.config`** file under the solution root directory?

Comment: Yes. It is there.

Comment: @MansoorOmrani, in the **`nuget.config`** file, have you set the correct username and password for the package source (the private Azure Artifacts feed) using '[**`<packageSourceCredentials>`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials)'?

Comment: Hi Back @BrightRan. No. I did not. I think it should not be necessary. The artifact feed is public. All the packages are publicly available and downloadable.

Comment: You may be right. It requires authentication when accessing nuget feeds. I used <packageSourceCredentials> as you suggested, however I didn't succeed with it. Although, I specify Username/Password and authentication type, azure devi\ops returns a 401 error.

Comment: @MansoorOmrani, I have updated my above answer with more information about how to get the authentication of feed (see EDIT_2). Check and try it.

Comment: Thank you @BrightRan. I'll check the new settings and let you know (we are off on Tuesday/Friday, I'll check them on Saturday).

Comment: @MansoorOmrani, No problem. Please go ahead.

Comment: I tried EDIT 2 solutions. The first method didn't work (reports the same old error message 'Unable to load the service index for source'). The second method worked and nuget packages restored successfully, however the build step (next step) again ran into error, reporting that dotnet cannot find project.json in assets folder.

Comment: @MansoorOmrani, Does the same build work fine in Visual Studio on your local machine?

Comment: Yes. It builds locally in VS. I think the problem is with active directory in our company's network. I asked our network admin to investigate this. One solution I used finally and worked is that, I used a different nuget feed outside AzureDevOps, not azuredevops' artifact feed. This time the pipeline worked fine and everything went ok.